# How to convert SpannedString to Spannable

Tags: android, textview, spannable

Hello I have set some text in a textview.

```
TextView tweet = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
tweet.setText(Html.fromHtml(sb.toString()));
```

Then I need to convert the text of the `TextView` into `Spannble`. So I did this like:

```
Spannable s = (Spannable) tweet.getText();
```

I need to convert it `Spannable` because I passed the `TextView` into a function:

```
    private void stripUnderlines(TextView textView) {
            Spannable s = (Spannable) textView.getText();
            URLSpan[] spans = s.getSpans(0, s.length(), URLSpan.class);
            for (URLSpan span : spans) {
                int start = s.getSpanStart(span);
                int end = s.getSpanEnd(span);
                s.removeSpan(span);
                span = new URLSpanNoUnderline(span.getURL());
                s.setSpan(span, start, end, 0);
            }
            textView.setText(s);
        }

private class URLSpanNoUnderline extends URLSpan {
        public URLSpanNoUnderline(String url) {
            super(url);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
        }
    }
```

This shows no error/warning. But throwing a Runtime Error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannedString cannot be cast to android.text.Spannable
```

How can I convert the SpannedStringt/text of the textview into Spannble? Or can I do the same task with SpannedString inside the function?

Comment: Terrible when UI guys decide to make links with no underlines huh? Going through same thing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> How can I convert the SpannedStringt/text of the textview into Spannble?

`new SpannableString(textView.getText())` should work.

> Or can I do the same task with SpannedString inside the function?

Sorry, but `removeSpan()` and `setSpan()` are methods on the `Spannable` interface, and `SpannedString` does not implement `Spannable`.

Comment: `new SpannableString(textView.getText())` I don't need this because `textView.getText()` is already `SpannedString`. I need to convert `textView.getText()` into `Spannable`. Is there any way?

Comment: @typedef: Please re-read my answer. Please note that I am having you construct a **`SpannableString`**. `SpannableString` implements `Spannable`. `SpannedString` does not.

Comment: Sir, then how can I convert the underline of of the text of a textview. Can you give me some hints?

Comment: No problem, after applying it `new SpannableString(textView.getText())` its working!

Comment: @CommonsWare pls fix your article here - http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/10/23/linkify-autolink-need-custom-urlspan.html according to this your answer.

Comment: in my case when I am using new SpannableString(textView.getText()) the underline is not being removed.                                                                Hence I have written my code like this                                                                               try {
                URLSpanNoUnderline.removeUnderlines((Spannable)txtAboutText.getText());
            }catch (Exception e){
                URLSpanNoUnderline.removeUnderlines(new SpannableString(txtAboutText.getText()));
            }

Answer (score 2):

This should be the correct work around. Its late tho but someone might need it in the future

```
private void stripUnderlines(TextView textView) {
        SpannableString s = new SpannableString(textView.getText());
        URLSpan[] spans = s.getSpans(0, s.length(), URLSpan.class);
        for (URLSpan span : spans) {
            int start = s.getSpanStart(span);
            int end = s.getSpanEnd(span);
            s.removeSpan(span);
            span = new URLSpanNoUnderline(span.getURL());
            s.setSpan(span, start, end, 0);
        }
        textView.setText(s);
    }



private class URLSpanNoUnderline extends URLSpan {
    public URLSpanNoUnderline(String url) {
        super(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        super.updateDrawState(ds);
        ds.setUnderlineText(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately none of these worked for me but after fiddling around with all of your solutions I found something that worked.

It will error casting the textView.getText() to Spannable unless you specify it as SPANNABLE

Also Notice from @CommonsWare's page:

Note that you do not want to call setText() on the TextView, thinking that you would be replacing the text with the modified version. You are modifying the TextView’s text in place in this fixTextView() method, and therefore setText() is not necessary. Worse, if you are using android:autoLink, setText() would cause Android go back through and add URLSpans again.

```
accountAddressTextView.setText(accountAddress, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

stripUnderlines(accountAddressTextView);

private void stripUnderlines(TextView textView) {
    Spannable entrySpan = (Spannable)textView.getText();
    URLSpan[] spans = entrySpan.getSpans(0, entrySpan.length(), URLSpan.class);

    for (URLSpan span: spans) {
            int start = entrySpan.getSpanStart(span);
            int end = entrySpan.getSpanEnd(span);
            entrySpan.removeSpan(span);
            span = new URLSpanNoUnderline(entrySpan.subSequence(start, end).toString());
            entrySpan.setSpan(span, start, end, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it has helped me!

Answer (score 0):

If you specify `BufferType.SPANNABLE` when setting the `TextView`'s text, then when getting the text you can cast it to `Spannable`

```
myTextView.setText("hello", TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
...
...
...
Spannable str = (Spannable) myTextView.getText();
```

Comment: Into the layout, the `textView` can also have `android:bufferType="spannable"` which is convenient